# Redirect response multiple times in Grails

Tags: grails, redirect, filter

Is it possible to redirect a response many times between controllers? If I try to redirect response inside a controller and then in after method of a Filter I did a redirect I got this exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - CannotRedirectException occurred when processing request: [GET] /ac/customer/index
Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
```

Is there any alternative way to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

There is no problem with redirecting a response many times between controllers, but you can can redirect only one time inside a action. Check you action method and verify you always exit the method after calling redirect (redirect don't means return).

This is wrong:

```
class MyController{

def myAction = {
   if(params.myparam){ redirect(uri:'/') }
   redirect(uri:'/foo')
   }

}
```

In this example if 'myparam' is present redirect is issued two times inside the action and this is bad.

This is correct

class MyController{

```
def myAction = {
   if(params.myparam){ 
   return redirect(uri:'/') 
   }
   redirect(uri:'/foo')
   }

}
```

Pay attention using closures and return inside closures. The return inside a closure don't exit from the main action but from the closure itsef

This is wrong

```
class MyController{

    def myAction = {
       withForm {
          return redirect(uri:'/') 
       }.invalidToken {
          // bad request
       }
       redirect(uri:'/foo')
       }

    }
```

Because with a valid two redirects are called.

This is correct:

class MyController{

```
    def myAction = {
       def formIsValid
       withForm {
          formIsValid = true
       }.invalidToken {
          formIsValid = false
       }

       if(formIsValid){ 
         return redirect(uri:'/') 
       }

       redirect(uri:'/foo')
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forward`: *Purpose: Forwards a request from one controller to the next without issuing an HTTP redirect.* Take a look at it in [grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Use

```
   chain(action:'', model:[pass any params here including any message]
```

Here is the documentation for chain: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/chain.html